# Where to download Honeycomb Gallery sample app?

Tags: android, android-studio

I know that the Honeycomb Gallery sample app is a long long time ago. However, I really need it now for some reasons. Anyone knows where can I get this ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can find it in `SdkManager's` smaple.

Comment: Yes, thank you actually found it lol. Thought only the recent one are there.